# Best Way to Integrate Wireless Scanners with ERP

Tags: barcode-scanner, erp

I would like to get some wireless barcode scanners with a display to use with my ERP system for inventory management.  A few things I would like to be able to do are:

- Allow a user to scan an item tag, type in a quantity, scan a destination inventory location tag, and have the ERP system move the inventory to that destination.
- Allow a user to scan an item tag and have the scanner display a listing of all the inventory locations that contain that item.
- Allow a user to scan a tracking number and mark that box as shipped in the ERP system.

I have an old ERP system, so I'm operating under the assumption that there is no off-the-shelf solution for this.  My initial though is to make an internal web site which has all the functionality that I need, and get scanners with a mobile OS and browser.

Is that a good way of going about this, and are there other methods that I should be considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barcode scanners typically act as keyboard-type devices. You scan a code and it "types" in the code value followed by a line feed. So all the rest you have to implement yourself. Typically you have a data entry form and just set focus to the textbox where the barcode should be scanned in, and script the rest in the ERP.

Comment: Would you recommend having the data entry screen as a web page?  I also thought about writing software for the scanner, but I can't find any information about how to do that.

Comment: A web form could cause issues because of browser particularities (if you use Firefox for example it will set focus on the URL instead of the field you want), or response time (you probably do not want to have to wait for 2-3 seconds every time you scan something for the postback). As for programming the scanner, that depends on the scanner. The cheap ones are dumb devices, they take no programming. If you have a nice expensive one, then you can probably program it to POST to a webpage or web service all by itself. Check its docs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.